# HttpWebRequest with basic authentication fails with 401 error for DefaultNetworkCredentials

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, basic-authentication, networkcredentials

I am testing an application with a local Web server (IIS, Windows 8), the site requires Basic authentication, and as long as I explicitly pass my credentials, everything works fine:

```
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("User", "Password", "Domain");
request.PreAuthenticate = true;
```

But I would like to use integrated security, so I tried to change the first line as follows:

```
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

(I also tried DefaultCredentials)

I checked the network traffic with Fiddler, and I see that in the second case Http request is sent without an authorization header, so it's not surprising that it fails. But why?

UPDATE. I believe I misunderstood default credentials concept. DefaultNetworkCredentials may not be used to generate basic authentication header, it must be a user/password pair. So this behavior is by design.

Comment: May be a silly question, but did you turn on integrated authentication for the website in IIS? You'll see a header in the response (from memory: www-authenticate negotiate) stating what authentication mechanisms the server accepts.

Comment: You need to configure delegation if you want the client credentials to leave the boundary of the web server that is acting as a client to another server. NTLM cannot be delegated. You could use Kerberos.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, but everything occurs on the same server. It's just my local machine.

Comment: @dash, if I only enable basic authentication, then it works with explicitly set user/password and fails with DefaultNetworkCredentials. If I enable both basic and Windows authentication, then Negotiate is selected so I can't test Basic.

Comment: Browser will try basic first, and then the *best* one it supports out of the list of remaining methods. In this instance, as you are on Windows, running against IIS, it's not surprising it tries Negotiate over Basic. See http://support.microsoft.com/?id=264921

Comment: Yes @dash I know that Negotiate wins over Basic. My scenario is when ONLY Basic is enabled, and then request fails with DefaultNetworkCredentials but succeeds with explicitly set credentials. I wonder why DefaultNetworkCredentials are not translated to proper authentication headers.

Comment: I'd be surprised if it popped your windows credentials into a basic header as they are plain text - it would be a great way to harvest  network credentials :-)

Comment: Ah I misunderstood the whole thing, thanks @dash

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to people who commented on the topic, I realized that I misunderstood the concept of default credentials. They can't be used in the case then only Basic authentication is enabled, so this is the correct behavior.